# Change border-color of inputfield on firebase-ui

Tags: html, css

I am using firebase authUI. Here is a [demo](https://fir-ui-demo-84a6c.firebaseapp.com/widget#recaptcha=normal): Click on `Sign in with Email`

I try to change the color of the 'blue' underline that is appearing when clicking in the input field. But I just can't figure out which element in the css I would need to change. I tried almost everything but I am missing something here. Maybe someone has an idea for me?

I only found out how to change the color of this border when it is not clicked:

```
.firebaseui-textfield.mdl-textfield .firebaseui-input {
    border-color: rgb(209,74,74);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add the class `.is-focused` manually to the div which contains the input and label.

That will force the focus state which you can inspect and modify the source accordingly.

I had a look myself, and if you want to change the border color, then add this...

```
.firebaseui-textfield.mdl-textfield .firebaseui-label::after {
    background-color: magenta;
}
```

Change the color as you wish. You might need to use important to override it.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. almost 1 hour to find it in console but no luck

Answer (score 2):

For Ionic users, place it at the end of your *variables.scss* file.

Don't forget the `!important` keyword.

Example to change buttons, text border, progress-bar and links color:

```css
.progressbar {
    background-color: var(--ion-color-primary) !important;
}

.mdl-button--raised.mdl-button--colored {
    background-color: var(--ion-color-primary) !important;
}

.mdl-button.mdl-js-button.mdl-button--primary {
    color: var(--ion-color-primary) !important;
}

.firebaseui-textfield.mdl-textfield.firebaseui-label::after {
    background-color: var(--ion-color-primary) !important;
}

a.firebaseui-link {
    color: var(--ion-color-primary) !important;
}

.progressbar {
    background-color: var(--ion-color-primary) !important;
}

.bufferbar {
    background-image: none !important;
    background-color: var(--ion-color-secondary)
}

.auxbar {
    background-image: none !important;
    background-color: var(--ion-color-primary) !important;
}
```

Result:
[image: screenshot of firebaseui with custom colors]